# How to tune Idea Intellij Ultimate so it doesn't crash on a 16GB host?

Tags: javascript, java, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-15

I have idea ultimate

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-192.7142.36, built on October 29, 2019
Licensed to Bootstrap Styled / Dimitri Kopriwa
Subscription is active until October 12, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.4+10-b304.77 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.3.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1896M
Cores: 8
Registry: 
Non-Bundled Plugins: Lombook Plugin, net.ashald.envfile, cn.wuzhizhan.plugin.mybatis, ru.adelf.idea.dotenv
```

When I work with multiple windows/workspace, it often gets slow to index, then become stuck or I have to wait forever.

I work with

- npm
- java

Both needs to reindex when I clean for the first with `rm -rf node_modules && npm i` and the second when I upgrade a dependency.

I also do local link in my nodes project, and sometimes it install in chain.

- I have read https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html and
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html

Documentation says default `-Xmx is 2048`, while `/opt/idea-latest/bin/idea64.vmoptions` was set to `Xmx 700mb`

- Why such difference and which one should I trust?
- I have increased this value to 8GB, I have 16GB, is it wise?
- Is there anything I can tune in order to get my IDEA work properly with multiple windows/workspace

Comment: Should be unnecessary and it's probably counter productive (what you have done so far). First make sure your video card drivers are up to date. Then make sure your JDK is up to date. [11.0.7](https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot) - where did you get your current JDK? Next make sure your code is on a SSD. Finally consider adding RAM to **the machine**. 16GB is not what it used to be.

Comment: 1\ it's up to date (lenovo x1 carbon gen 7 2019), 2\ I use jdk 8 (1.8.0_231), I can't upgrade yet. 3\ Oracle website  4\ It's a brand new SSD with 1TB. 4\ I can't add ram on the x1 carbon

Comment: Clear any unwanted cache/space you don't need or tmp files, and plugins that aren't required can be removed/not installed.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa *I use jdk 8 (1.8.0_231), I can't upgrade yet.* - that is not correct. "Runtime version: 11.0.4+10-b304.77 amd64" says you are using 11.0.4 - and that is not up to date. And there was no "official" JRE for Java 11. Shame about the RAM. 16GB really is not what it used to be. And I would guess your computer uses shared video/system ram. That really is a shame.

Comment: Looks like you hit [Ubunty kernel bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1872001). Check this thread for a solution: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2269

Comment: I am on Debian 10.3, with Linux dka 5.3.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.3.9-2~bpo10+1 (2019-11-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @ElliottFrisch oh sorry, I was speaking about the JDK used by my java program, perhaps IDEA is not up to date but people told me on freenode that the 2020 edition is worst. I did not install any JRE myself for intellij, so it's the one provided by intellij itself

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa Ubuntu is a debian derived OS, I would follow [that link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2269) (Andrey provided).

Comment: I already clicked on that link and I am already on kernel 5.3 of linux and I am not using the 2020 version  of idea intellij ultimate

Comment: Cool. Still sounds like the same bug to me. You could try some of the suggestions there. Or you could assume it's totally unrelated in which case I have already offered some suggestions and I'm fresh out of helpful advice for you. Maybe someone else will have an idea. The "bleeding edge" is called that for a reason. I don't have time for that any more.

Comment: It seems that you are right. Someone just added a comment and is using the same kernel and idea version as me. Not sure what to do to fix that. Any suggestion?